# Crash : objc_msgSend() selector name: _didReceiveConnectionCacheKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, magicalrecord

I implemented an NSTimer which call a simple method :

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:kTimerDelay target:self selector:@selector(synchronise) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

This method builds an NSDictionnary, searches objects in CoreData Context with there ids and enumerates :

```
- (void)synchronise
{
    NSDictionary *postDict = @{...};
    NSArray *objectIdList = [postDict valueForKeyPath:@"object_items.@allKeys"];
    NSArray *objectList = [P_CoreDataObject MR_findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", objectIdList]];
    MyServiceService *myService = [[MyServiceService alloc] init];
    for (P_CoreDataObject *object in objectList) {
        [myService sendLink:object.link_url success:nil failure:nil];
    }
}
```

I call MR_findAll on an other object to build the NSDictionnary and it works well, but in some rare cases, it crashs !

Does someone have any idea how to understand this crash ?

The stack trace :

> objc_msgSend() selector name: _didReceiveConnectionCacheKey:
>
> Thread 0: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018417680c
>   pread + 8 1   libsqlite3.dylib                     0x0000000184ab0b9c
>   sqlite3_snprintf + 13660 2   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x0000000184acfb20 sqlite3_log + 5472 3   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x0000000184aceab8 sqlite3_log + 1272 4   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x0000000184af223c sqlite3_step + 60112 5   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x0000000184af3620 sqlite3_value_text + 3412 6   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x0000000184ae5088 sqlite3_step + 6428 7   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x0000000184ae3960 sqlite3_step + 500 8   CoreData
>   0x000000018604fab8 _execute + 144 9   CoreData
>   0x000000018605f988 -[NSSQLiteConnection
>   fetchResultSet:usingFetchPlan:] + 1644 10  CoreData
>   0x000000018616150c newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1560 11  CoreData
>   0x00000001860567e4 -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] +
>   536 12  CoreData                             0x0000000186056218
>   -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 596 13  CoreData                             0x000000018611d910 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 2620 14  CoreData
>   0x0000000186125d58 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform +
>   172 15  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001840415f0
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 12 16  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018404c89c _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 96 17  CoreData
>   0x00000001861185b0 _perform + 176 18  CoreData
>   0x0000000186055e70 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 296 19  CoreData
>   0x0000000186054938 -[NSManagedObjectContext
>   executeFetchRequest:error:] + 532 20  CoreData
>   0x00000001860f6318 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
>   _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 416 21  CoreData                             0x00000001860f6a44 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 344 22  CoreData
>   0x00000001860f8d80 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 104
>   23  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001840415f0
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 12 24  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018404c89c _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 96 25  CoreData
>   0x00000001860e86fc _perform + 208 26  CoreData
>   0x00000001860f6824 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 172 27  CoreData
>   0x0000000186054938 -[NSManagedObjectContext
>   executeFetchRequest:error:] + 532 28  Youboox
>   0x0000000100236268 __67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord)
>   MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke
>   (NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:54) 29  CoreData
>   0x00000001860ed080
>   developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 192 30 
>   CoreData                             0x00000001860ecf48
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 216 31  Youboox                              0x00000001002361ac +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord)
>   MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]
>   (NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:50) 32  Youboox
>   0x00000001002344d4 +[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders)
>   MR_findAllWithPredicate:inContext:]
>   (NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m:76) 33  Youboox
>   0x0000000100234568 +[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders)
>   MR_findAllWithPredicate:] (NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m:84)

EDIT : The craching thread stack trace

> Thread 18 Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000183c6dbc8 objc_msgSend + 8 1   CFNetwork
>   0x0000000184c3a518
>   SessionConnectionLoadable::_loaderClientEvent_DidReceiveConnectionCacheKey(HTTPConnectionCacheKey*)
>   + 52 2   CFNetwork                            0x0000000184cb9178 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader36protocolDidReceiveConnectionCacheKeyEP22HTTPConnectionCacheKey_block_invoke
>   + 36 3   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000184041630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20 4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001840415f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12 5   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000018404d634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 860 6   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001840450f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 460 7   libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x000000018404f504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 724 8
>   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018404f224
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000184255470 _pthread_wqthread + 1088 10 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000184255020 start_wqthread
>   + 0

Comment: That's odd.  This thread doesn't mention the method implicated in the crash.  Are you sure it says that thread 0 is the crashing thread?

Comment: Dammit ! You're right ! The thread 18 crached. I update my question.

Comment: I'm getting this crash also.  In my case, it is occurring when my app is performing a background app refresh from application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:  I suspect the problem is that I'm using a foreground URLSession, and instead should be using a background one.  Does this match your situation at all?

Comment: Yes I'm using Background Transfer Service with URLSession, and I use both, background and forground sessions. I just realized that I set a "FinishEventsForBackgroundURLSessionBlock" to every URLSession. 
Could this cause my crash ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387246/how-to-debug-and-solve-a-crash-in-afnetworking

Comment: Hi, having the same issue.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3530
Is any of you using AFNetworking?
Also this link might help
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html