# How to debug and solve a crash in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, afnetworking-2

My iOS app uses AFNetworking (2.6.1), and my highest ranking crash is :

```
Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0004000128ab38a0
```

This is how most stack traces look like in Crashlytics:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180e29bc8 objc_msgSend + 8
1  CFNetwork                      0x181df6518 SessionConnectionLoadable::_loaderClientEvent_DidReceiveConnectionCacheKey(HTTPConnectionCacheKey*) + 56
2  CFNetwork                      0x181e75178 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader36protocolDidReceiveConnectionCacheKeyEP22HTTPConnectionCacheKey_block_invoke + 40
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1811fd630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1811fd5f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x181209634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1812010f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18120b504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18120b224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181411470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181411020 start_wqthread + 4
```

I don't use kvo, and my app uses location and stays in the background at all times.

Any ideas on how to debug / recreate (I can't manage to recreate the issue in a simulator or on a device) ?
Even catching the exception, without knowing where it is or how to handle it correctly would suffice in this case...

Comment: Check this link to how create an Exception breakpoint, it will point the line that is causing the crash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: If only I could recreate it in a simulator / device - that would help, but I get these crashes via Crashlytics as they only happen "in the wild"

Comment: @UlyssesR `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` *is not a thrown exception*.   An exception backtrace will never work for that kind of crash.

Comment: Hi, having a very similar issue.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3530

is any of you using backgroundFetch and might consider that this crash is done while app NOT in foreground?

Also this link might help
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

Comment: this issue only seems to happen on iOS 9 and not on iOS 10